# QR-Codes alternative for low resolution

Tags: image-processing, qr-code

The smallest QR-Codes to my knowledge are 25x25 blocks and thus if I want to detect the QR-Code in an image the part containing it needs to be at least 25x25 pixels.

Is there a smaller alternative (with a library implementation in python)?

The code should be able to encode at least 8 Bit of information.
No information encoding with different colors should be used, the code should only use black and white.

Comment: it is not clear what you want and there are many things wrong with the information in your post. please read something about 2d codes. your post cannot be answered in a meaningful manner as your requirements just don't make any sense.

Comment: A barcode maybe? Not sure what you mean.